# How Do I lazily load DataTypes other than Lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph

I'm starting to understand the power of Haskell and how lazy loading can be exploited in ways such as

```
main = do
  s <- getContents
  let r = map processIt (lines s)
  putStr (unlines r)
```

But the trouble i'm having is extending this kind of "Say whats in the data structure up front but get it when you need it" functionality for other datatypes.

For instance I have a graph type.

```
type Key = String
data Node = Node { key :: Key, links :: [Node] }
```

I want to write pure code that acts on this graph (Strait forward searching algorithms) no matter how it is built but I want the Nodes to lazily fill themselves when I get to them.

I think I need a way to specify up front what is in the graph and how to fill it (Some sort of recursive definition) but I'm having trouble seeing how.
Something like

```
loadGraph :: Key -> Node
loadGraph k =
  let (key,edges) = getNodeAndEdgesFromInternetOrDatabase k in
  Node key (map loadGraph edges)
```

I feel like this is close but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Help and Tips would be appreciated. (especially things like the type of getNodeAndEdgesFromInternetOrDatabase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy IO is generally implemented using [`unsafeInterleaveIO`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v%3aunsafeInterleaveIO), which delays the side effects of an `IO` action until its result is demanded.

For your example, it would go something like this.

```
loadGraph :: Key -> IO Node
loadGraph k = unsafeInterleaveIO $ do
  (key, edges) <- getNodeAndEdgesFromInternetOrDatabase k
  edges' <- mapM loadGraph edges
  return (Node key edges')
```

Since `unsafeInterleaveIO` is wrapping every call to `loadGraph`, this will only load that subgraph when you try evaluating it.

Lazy IO is frowned upon by some, as it makes it difficult to reason about the order in which the side effects happen. However, I think for your application it might be suitable, as long as you're careful in how you implement `getNodeAndEdgesFromInternetOrDatabase`.

Comment: How do you know where the file's read pointer will be when the node is evaluated?  I.e. Does it work if the nodes are needed in a different order from the order they appear in the file, or does the evaluation of the last node force all of the prior nodes to be evaluated?

Comment: @pat: This assumes that `getNodeAndEdgesFromInternetOrDatabase` does not depend on being called in any specific order, so in the case of a file, it would have to read from absolute offsets. If you want to force the actions to be executed in order while still retaining laziness, check out [the `lazyio` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyio), which gives you a monad for doing this.

Comment: You'd also need to assume that the nodes and edges are retrieved in some order, and you could depend on that order to know that e.g. all the edges connected to a particular node have been loaded, or you'd end up scanning the file to check every edge if it's connected to a node.